# How to Profile Google App Engine Java Servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, profiling

I have a java google app engine servlet that writes to the datastore amongst other things. It runs really fast locally. However, on app engine server each request nears 2 seconds (event after ramp up). How can I go about profiling my servlet to identify which pieces of my code are taking long?

So far the only way I can think of is to log system time at various points in the code and then look at the logs and work it out... is there a better technique to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats.html), a tool written specifically for profiling RPC calls on App Engine.